# Request to create / enable syntax highlight for M language

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

We have increasing number of questions about [power-query](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-query).

It would be great to apply syntax highlight for M language code in questions.

Comment: I don't see the language M in the dropdown. Are these alternative styles that could be used? https://i.stack.imgur.com/wABQr.png

Comment: @SathyajithBhat what is that drop-down you have on your screenshot?

Comment: here is definition file for Notepad++, I don't know if it could help. https://sascha-kasper.com/download/m-power-query-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad/

Comment: the drop down is a list of languages we(Moderators) can associate to a tag. We can't upload any new ones though. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/133693 https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md